# Build matrix with 0 values instead of NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am storing my sites google analytics results in a table in with these columns:

```
date        domain      source          session_count
2020-04-06  xyz.com     organic search  50
2020-04-07  123.net     direct          40
```

The first 3 columns are the compound keys.

There are different combinations which are missing data, because there wasn't any page views, in that day, or in that specific source.

I would like to built a matrix view where all dates, all domains, all sources show the `session_count`, and if there is none it would ideally show `0` with `ISNULL` function.

I have a separate date dimension table, which I join (full outer join), then I can see all the dates (even the ones which don't have any entry), but the different domains and different sources are missing.

Example output:

```
date        domain      source          session_count
2020-04-05  xyz.com     organic search  0
2020-04-05  xyz.com     direct          0
2020-04-05  123.net     organic search  0
2020-04-05  123.net     direct          0
2020-04-06  xyz.com     organic search  50
2020-04-06  xyz.com     direct          0
2020-04-06  123.net     organic search  0
2020-04-06  123.net     direct          0
```

Please help me achieve this view.

Comment: Can you say columns of separated tables and your joins.

Comment: If you need the different domains and sources as well, you could create a temporary table or CTE containing those. Then you simply do another full outer join with that, and you'd be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return all the possible combinations, besides a date dimension table you also need a domains and sources tables.

Without them you can get the same result calculating them first on CTEs, although the performance would be slower:

Supposing that your date dimension table is called Calendar, and your google analytics results table is called GoogleData, then your query would be:

```
with Domains as (
  select distinct domain
  from GoogleData
),
Sources as (
  select distinct source
  from GoogleData
) 
select Calendar.date, Domains.domain, Sources.source, 
       isnull(GoogleData.session_count, 0) as session_count
from Calendar
     cross join Domains 
     cross join Sources
     left join GoogleData on GoogleData.date = Calendar.date and 
                             GoogleData.domain = Domains.domain and 
                             GoogleData.source = Sources.source
```

Comment: Works exactly as I wanted. Thanks.